# DOMDocument simple wrapper - how to adjust left side of appendChild

Tags: wrapper, domdocument, php-7.3

Building a very simple DOMDocument wrapper.

Currently the usage is only for creating elements, its value and append them to defined parent.

**Question:** Is it possible to replace a text of a DOMDocument command?

**Wanted result:** the body tag should append html tag.

**Planned solution:** 
I would need the "xml" in appendChild to be able to be replacable by the sent-in variable $appendTo.

```
$this->xml->appendChild($this->tempName);
```

**Run.php**

```
<?php

include 'logics.class.php';


$build = new Logics();


$build->createDoc();

$build->BuildElement('html', 'Ericsson', 'xml');
$build->BuildElement('body', 'Nokia', 'html');

$build->printDocument();
```

**Logics**

```
<?php

class Logics {

  public function createDoc()
  {
    $this->xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $this->xml->formatOutput = true;
  }

  public function buildElement($elementName, $value, $appendTo)
  {

    $this->tempName = $this->xml->createElement(
      $elementName,
      $value,
    );

    $this->xml->appendChild($this->tempName); // Plan to replace xml with $appendTo

  }

  public function saveDocument()
  {
    $this->xml->save("result.xml");
  }

  public function printDocument()
  {
    echo $this->xml->saveXML();
  }


}
```